# thinclient showing database error after deployment

Tags: database

I developed an exam software using C# and installed in local server machine.

It is working fine in server (Windows Server 2012 r2) but shows database error as "readonly" in thinclient.

What can I do?

Comment: We need more information. What kind of database is it? (SQL Server. MySQL , Access, etc.). What kind of thin client? What language?

Comment: SQL : - Microsoft SQL (.mdf) And Thinclint : - G1pcs And Language of Programe C# Using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: NOW it is working perfectly on thinclint if run it as Administrator.